# How to view exe's SmartScreen reputation score?

Tags: .net, windows, security, codeplex, smartscreen

Users who download my freeware application from codeplex get SmartScreen alert in Win 8:

"Windows SmartScreen prevented an unrecgnised application from starting.  Running this application might put your PC at risk."

You have to know to click on "More Info" and "Run Anyway" button, to execute it.

I think it just started to happen recently, so not sure what caused it.   Maybe a recent windows update.  To counter this screen, I signed my EXE with digital signature, which means MS will start using it towards reputation score for my application.

The question is, is there any way so see reputation score for this application and suggestions what else can be improved?

I am not sure if most users even know to click on more info link to be able to "Run Anyway", and end up just not using my application after downloading.

Comment: *To counter this screen, I signed my EXE with digital signature* I believe the digital signature helps but if you get enough reputation with build 1 that just translates into faster reputation for build 2 i.e. Different exe = unique reputation.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Different .EXEs will have different reputation only if unsigned. Signed EXEs build reputation by certificate. [Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/03/22/smartscreen-174-application-reputation-building-reputation.aspx)